# Why does this HTML fail in IE8/9 only when added with JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

i am using chrome. i am using a "div" with "float: left" and "float: right" buttons. The page is views in atleast all browser ( not IE8-IE9 ).

Here is Chrome, IE8-IE9 (generated with javascript), and IE8-IE9 Normal HTML code Preview.
[ full image preview ]
http://i52.tinypic.com/28878tk.jpg
i dont know what is the problem, div css float problem or javascript problem.

here is css code:

```
 #middleside01 {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background: url(rp_images2/blue_mid.png);
    width: 715px;
    height: 250px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    }

.flagbtn1 {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background: url(rp_images2/country_box.png);
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    height: 45px;

}

.flagbtn2 {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    background: url(rp_images2/country_box.png);
    margin-top: 6px;
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    height: 45px;

}
```

And here is Javascript code:

```
function insert_btn(im_url,id,flagid,name){
var tbl='<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);"><div class="flagbtn'+id+'">';
if(ratepg==false){flagid='44';}
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnf"><img src="'+im_url+'large/'+flagid+'.gif" alt="'+name+'" onError="this.src=\''+im_url+'large/noimgbig.jpg\';" /></div>';
//if(name.length>=30)name=name.substr(0,25)+"...";
if(ratepg==true){
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnt rt-font">> <a onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);" class="ft1">'+name+' ('+flagid+')</a></div></div></a>'; } else {
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnt rt-font">> <a onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);" class="ft1">'+name+'</a></div></div></a>'; }
if(id=='2'){
    tbl+='<div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
    return tbl;
}
```

i used clearfix method, but it not works. What could the problem be?

## [7:59 PM - 10-12-2011]

I got my Solution by removing this from first line of javascript:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);">
```

Thankyou so much to all. Someone said that why i use some requesting sentence. that's because i am new on stackoverflow, and it is my first question. so it happend.

Thankx again to All.

Comment: What is your `clearfix` class?

Comment: @megas that's why you are capable to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove extra closing ( starred part )

```
function insert_btn(im_url,id,flagid,name){
var tbl='<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);"><div class="flagbtn'+id+'">';
if(ratepg==false){flagid='44';}
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnf"><img src="'+im_url+'large/'+flagid+'.gif" alt="'+name+'" onError="this.src=\''+im_url+'large/noimgbig.jpg\';" /></div>';
//if(name.length>=30)name=name.substr(0,25)+"...";
if(ratepg==true){
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnt rt-font">**>** <a onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);" class="ft1">'+name+' ('+flagid+')</a></div></div></a>'; } else {
    tbl+='<div class="flagbtnt rt-font">**>** <a onclick="ajax_cl(\''+flagid+','+name+'\', flagsfldr);" class="ft1">'+name+'</a></div></div></a>'; }
if(id=='2'){
    tbl+='<div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
    return tbl;
}
```